# Ethernet Webserver size limit

Tags: stm32, ethernet

I am using an STM32F407VG which acts as a simple webserver. I have an html file on an sd card which is 1611 bytes. When I use a file thats below 1415 bytes the page loads fine on the web browser, but anything above that does not. So I was wondering is there any limitations on the number of bytes that can be written to the ethernet controller??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to 802.3 ethernet standards you should be able to send 1500 (payload) size of MTU. This MTU is encapsulated inside ethernet header but lets not go there because this will get stripped off when the packet touches ethernet.

Ideally if you ping a hostname, the packet format should look like following: `1472 + 20 IP header + 8 ICMP header  = 1500`. But For me my home router adds another header called PPPoE and it looks like this:    `1464 + 20 IP header + 8 ICMP header + 8 PPPoE header = 1500`.

You can test it as well using following command:

```
Windows: ping hostname -f -l sizeofdata
BSD: ping -D -s sizeofdata hostname
Linux: ping -M do -s sizeofdata hostname
```

Now, for you its 1415, this you need to check what other application headers that are getting added. Also, DF bit is set or not, this could also cause a problem. The DF stands for "Don't Fragment" and packets larger than the MTU have to be fragmented to be transmitted.